# How to access generic parameter's companion object in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, inheritance, companion-object

Say that I have interfaces `IEntity` and `IEntityFactory` and a class `Person`. Imagine that I also have additional implementations of `IEntity` with their own unique properties, similar to `Person`.

I require that `Person` implements the properties of `IEntity` and the "static" methods of `IEntityFactory` on its companion object. I wish there were a way to enforce this, but there does not seem to be.

```kotlin
interface IEntityFactory<T : IData> {
    // a string like "entity.person" used for identifying object types across the wire
    val objectType: String
    // a function to get the class instance from a Map
    fun fromMap(map: Map<String, @Contextual Any?>): T
    // a function that checks if the given string meets the requirements to be of this object type
    fun isOfType(objectType: String?): Boolean
}
```

```kotlin
interface IEntity {
    val objectType: String
    val name: String
}
```

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class Person(
    override val objectType: String,
    override val name: String,
) : IEntity {

    companion object : IEntityFactory<Person> {
        override val objectType: String = "entity.person"
        override fun fromMap(map: Map<String, Any?>) = // do work
        override fun isOfType(objectType: String?) = // do work
    }
}
```

Now, say that I want to easily convert a `Map<String, Any>` to any of the `IEntities` given above. One way may be to create an extension function:

```kotlin
fun <T : IEntity> Map<String, String>.toData(): T? {
    val objectType = this["objectType"]!!.lowercase()
    if(T.isOfType(objectType)) return T.fromMap(this)
}
```

Obviously, the above code does not work: How is the compiler supposed to know that all implementations of `IEntity` implement their own `IEntityFactory<IEntity>>` (and consequently, their own implementations of `IEntity.fromMap()`?

What is a good (Kotlin-esque) way around this, since interfaces cannot enforce the implementation of the companion object?

**EDIT**:
In reference to @aSemy's proposal:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : IData> Map<String, String>.toData(): T? {
    return try {
        val jsonMap = Json.encodeToString(this)
        Json.decodeFromString(jsonMap)
    } catch (_: Exception) {
        null
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. `Person` class doesn't know anything about its companion class, it can't be referenced without reflection or a similar way. It is the opposite: the companion references `Person`. In your `toData()` function you should receive `IEntityFactory` and then the type of the entity can be inferred from it.

Comment: @broot Thanks for the quick insight. The first part makes sense, but I'm struggling to envision an implementation of the second part. Could you please give me an example if you have the time?

Comment: I see `@Serializable` - are you using Kotlinx Serialization? In which case, you could use `JsonObject` instead of `Map<String, Any?>`, and then decode to create a `Person`.

Comment: @aSemy Good observation, I am. I need the classes to be serializable to go over the wire. However, I'm actually not dealing with JSON objects when using `fromMap()`. It is beyond the scope of this question, but I get maps from TinkerPop traversals. EDIT: Maybe I could JSONify the Map that TinkerPop gives me and then try to deserialize it? Sounds messy, but what do you think? Down side is that it gives me less flexibility data-storage wise. TinkerPop does not support nested properties, so all properties on all of these objects would need to be flat unless I manipulate the map before serializing

Comment: Can you check to see if the `Map<String, Any?>` could be converted to a `JsonObject`, e.g. `Json.encodeToJsonElement(map)`? Then you could use KxS.

Comment: That's what I've just changed it too for now, check the edit on my OP

Comment: If you made `IEntityFactory` a sealed interface, and mapped all sealed subclasses to objects `IEntityFactory::class.sealedSubclasses.map { it.objectInstance ?: error("$it does not have EntityFactory") }.associateBy { it.objectType }`, and initialised it as a static property, then at least it would fail on startup. But personally I think using reflection like that is pretty hacky.

Comment: @aSemy Yes, that makes me feel gross just thinking about it. But maybe...

Comment: Regarding the example where `toData()` receives a factory. Well, your existing code should be fine. Just receive a factory and use it for `isOfType()` and `fromMap()`.

Comment: @broot How would I receive it, as an argument? If the caller is also generic, then I'd have to propagate that arg up the call chain, no?